# Long journal names or article titles break border with biblatex :(

Tags: biblatex

[The top border spill is a journal name, and the bottom spill is an article title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVRg5.png)

I am using the LaTex template my university provides. It runs on

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib,
bibstyle=numeric,
citestyle=authoryear,
sorting=none,
hyperref=true]
{biblatex}
```

, and I have added

```
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{9999}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9999}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9999}
```

I have checked biblatex's documentation, but it's just too long and detailed to be actually helpful for my level...Thanks for help in advance!

I have tried to look for penalty counters similar to that for the URL for journal name and paper title but failed :(